# HTML Service - Uncaught NetworkError: Form submission failed

Tags: google-apps-script, lastpass

I am working through the google example code for [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

I can't get the sample code to work for "Forms'. Is there an error in the code or is it something in my browser config?

The code is -

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var formBlob = formObject.myFile;
  var driveFile = DriveApp.createFile(formBlob);
  return driveFile.getUrl();
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
  function updateUrl(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
  }
</script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="myFile" type="file" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The error in the debug windows of my browser is

`Uncaught NetworkError: Form submission failed.`

Thanks in advance. Will Brown.

Comment: If you find an answer to a question you asked you should answer it as an answer and mark it as "answered". Editing the question like you did is not recommended and not easily visible to other users.

Comment: Ah thank you!  Note that you do indeed need to disable Lastpass, not just log out of it.

Comment: Since you have an answer to your question, you should add it as an answer to your question to help future readers. At least 2 others have found that LastPass was causing them the same problem, so modifying your question to help others find it will be a benefit to the community.

Comment: Disabling Lastpass isn't a silver bullet for this issue; others and myself don't have any extensions installed but have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error is not due to a code problem at all, rather it is an interaction between a browser plug-in and Google's authentication services. See [Issue 3339](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3339) and [Issue 4394](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4394).

If you're using the [LastPass](http://lastpass.com) password manager plugin, it must be disabled.

---

<sup><sub>PS: @user3531933 - if you add your own answer, just leave a comment for me, and I'll happily delete this and leave it to you.</sub></sup>