# Error when <input type="file"> is blank on a submitted form (Google App Script)

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script, forms, html-input

I'm creating a Google Web App (which is a HTML form) that will upload a file to a folder on My Drive. It's not required to have a file to upload, so there will be times where this input will essentially be "blank". The app works perfectly fine, except when you don't choose a file to upload. It spits out this error:  "Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." I have two files, the html file and the .gs file. Here's they are:

```js
/* The script is deployed as a web app and renders the form */
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FormFrontend.html');
}

/* This function will process the submitted form */
function uploadFiles(form) {
  try {
    /* Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved */
    var dropfolder = "Uploaded Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropfolder);

    /* Find the folder, create the folder if it does not exist */
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropfolder);
    }

    /* Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob */
    var blob = form.myFile;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);
    var urlstr = file.getUrl()

    /* Set the file description as the name of the uploader */
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.ContactName);

    /* Write response to spreadsheet */
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    var responses = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
    responses.appendRow([form.CompanyName, form.ContactName, form.PhoneNumber, form.Email, form.Date, form.Severity, form.Details, urlstr])

    /* As long as there's no errors you should se the below text */
    return "Form Submitted Successfully "

  } catch (error) {

    /* If there's an error, show the error message */
    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <!-- This is the actual HTML form -->
  <div id="theform">
    <form id="myForm">

      <p style="font-size:30px">Customer Form</p>

      Company Name:
      <input type="text" name="CompanyName">
      <br>Contact Name:
      <input type="text" name="ContactName">
      <br>Phone Number:
      <input type="text" name="PhoneNumber">
      <br>Contact Email:
      <input type="email" name="Email">
      <br>Date:
      <input type="date" name="Date">
      <br>Overall Severity: (1 Lowest, 5 Highest)
      <br>
      <input type="number" name="Severity" min="1" max="5" value="1">
      <br>Details:

      <br>
      <textarea name="Details" rows=10 cols=65></textarea>
      <br>
      <br>Additional File (Optional):
      <input type="file" name="myFile">
      <br>

      <!-- The submit button. It calls the server side function uploadFiles() on click -->
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.value='Submitting..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Here the results of the form submission will be displayed -->
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>

<!-- The function will be called after the Google Script has executed -->
<script>
  function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
  }
</script>
```

If have tried putting an IF statement around the "/* Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob */" section that tells it to just set urlstr to nothing if form.myFile is blank, but it still fails (but if you choose an actual file, it still completes successfully). I haven't been able to get anything helpful to show up in the logger either.

I'm fairly new to Google App Script, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up working. The .getContentType seems to always return "application/octet-stream" when it's left blank and checking to see if the returned content type is that specific one worked.

```
/* Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob */
var blob = form.myFile;
var contentType = blob.getContentType();

if (contentType != "application/octet-stream") {
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);
    var urlstr = file.getUrl();
    /* Set the file description as the name of the uploader */
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.ContactName);
 } else {
    var urlStr = "None given";
 }
```

Comment: I also want to mention this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244180/html-service-server-function-with-a-form) in case anyone has issues with file form submissions while having LastPass installed in your browser. It was a small issue I fought through.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check what is actually getting returned into the variable `blob`.

```
var blob = form.myFile;
```

Maybe check the type with JavaScript `typeOf`.

```
var whatsTheType = typeOf blob;
```

In this test function:

```
function testIt() { 
  var newTestFile = DriveApp.createFile('New Text File', 'Hello, world!');
  var myBlob = newTestFile.getBlob();

  var whatsTheType = typeof myBlob;
  Logger.log('whatsTheType: ' + whatsTheType);
}
```

JavaScript `typeof` returns the type of the blob as an "object".  If you check the `typeof`, and it's not an object, then the file wasn't uploaded.

Put in an `if` conditional check, rather than a "try/catch".  The "try/catch" obviously isn't keeping the code from dying.

```
if (whatsTheType === "object") {
  //Create the file
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);
};
```

Alternatively, you should be able to check the `value` property of the file picker to return a name, if a file was uploaded.  If there is no name for the uploaded file, then the user didn't use the file picker.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay as I've been busy with this pesky NAS lately. Sadly, it returns the type as an object whether or not you select a file.

Comment: In the end your post made us look up the class of the blob and eventually find what we need, so thanks for your help!